Worst mold ever, or something else?
We're selling a house built in 2016 and the buyer's inspector says they found black mold. It's a utility closet under the stairs and only visible when you peel back the insulation. When I look at google images of black mold, it doesn't look so thick and solid like this. And it hasn't spread to any of the surrounding materials (wood or insulation). The material is (I believe) a plywood that is an exterior wall. We also found out a nearby dryer vent was failing, but when we opened the wall to fix that, it didn't have anything close to this inside.
I noticed a couple other things:
The bottom horizontal piece of wood shows some evidence of moisture, but this is sitting on the concrete foundation and I've heard that this should be treated lumber, but is not. So that could be a separate source of moisture, not the thing causing the supposed mold.
The bolt head has some rust on it.
I'm not surprised there's been some moisture because of the dryer issue and the fact that this is tucked under the stairs and has no moving air.
My questions:
Is this actually mold, or could it be some material applied to the wood (e.g., a moisture barrier)
If it is mold, is the dryer issue the likely culprit if there's no evidence of a leak? If so, what does remediation look like?
Any thoughts?



That does look odd, that mold is only on one surface. You may need to get a sample and have it tested.   Possibly tar?

possible humidity insulation layer
